# Android Custom Scrollbar Like Google's Google Now Launcher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-scrollbar

I have found out that is indeed possible to set a custom scroll bar for an android Listview. I am wondering how I can use the custom scrollbar that was used in Google's Google Now Launcher.

[image: Google Now Custom Scrollbar]

How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: you can use fast scroll for that